# Как исправить ошибку в форме внесения новостей (TinyMCE)?

Tags: php, javascript, form

Установил на сайт форму ввода новостей, естественно установил TinyMCE. Но непонятно, почему-то от редактора TinyMCE выводятся только одна треть (курсив, полу жирный, шрифт и тд) из всех возможных методов форматирования текста,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "elm_content"
    });
</script>
<form method='post' action='submitter.php'>
<input type='text' name='body'><p>
Выбирите имя<select name='metatitle'>
<option value='1'>женское имя</option>
<option value='2'>мужское имя</option>
</select><p>
<textarea id="elm_content" rows="20" cols="59" name="title"></textarea><p>
<input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Comment: код инициализации компонента и порцию данных, которые туда попадают в студию!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

добавь
tinyMCE.init({
…
theme : “advanced”,

а вообще http://tinymce.ru/faq/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- TinyMCE -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    language : "ru",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/content.css",
    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
    // Style formats
    style_formats : [

{title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],
        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {

username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"

}

});
</script>

<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```